# How to make a multi-line x axis title with mathematical expressions in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotmath

```
xlab(expression(paste("CO"^"2", " concentration", "\n Lolium perenne")))
```

This is my current coding.
With my xlab I want to have CO^2 concentration on one line, and then "Lolium perenne" beneath that but it also needs to be in italics. Currently this code places "concentration" on the line above "CO^2" and "Lolium Perenne".
Please help!

Comment: Do provide a reproducible example. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on how to create one.

Comment: Newlines are not possible using `expression(...)` natively, but a workaround is to use `expression(atop(CO^2*" concentration", italic("Lolium perenne")))`

Comment: I have provided an answer with a reproducible example. Feel free to copy into your question. I didn't want to completely rewrite your question. I have also included @Brian's suggestion as the answer. In general, on SO, we want helpful answers in the "Answer" part, not as comment. Comments are open to deletion at any time.

Answer (score 2):

Let's turn this into a reproducible example and then answer, using the approach @Brian suggested.

The following doesn't work. The x axis title is all on one line:

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(124)
d <- data.frame(x = rnorm(50),
                y = rnorm(50))

ggplot(d, aes(x, y)) + geom_point() +
  xlab(expression(paste("CO"^"2", " concentration", "\n Lolium perenne")))
```

[image]

However, using the `atop()` function, we can obtain this result:

```
ggplot(d, aes(x, y)) + geom_point() +
  xlab(expression(atop(CO[2]*" concentration", italic("Lolium perenne"))))
```

[image]

We have typeset "Lolium perenne" in italics, using the `italic()` function. We have also written CO2 with a subscript, which is presumably what is needed here.

Comment: I didn't post it as an answer because I think it's a workaround with too many drawbacks to be generally recommendable. Trying to solve that sort of problem has been on my backburner for a while. Thanks for your effort. (Also now that I see it rendered, they should be `CO[2]`, not `CO^2`).

Comment: I made the change to `CO[2]`.